# How do I test using Roboelectric the code that is executed inside onGlobalLayout from a ViewTreeObserver?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I have the following code in my fragment:

```
public void someMethod()
{
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout()
                    {    

                    // code that I want to test

                    }
                 }
}
```

However, when I try to test this method I am not able to run the code inside the GlobalLayoutListener. I tried in different ways to force the execution of the listener but when I check debugging the scrollerView does not have any GlobalLayoutListeners.

The code I want to test is inside a Fragment and this what I already tryied to do in my test:

```
SupportFragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment( fragment );
fragment.scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().dispatchOnGlobalLayout();
```

I have also tried:

```
shadowOf(fragment.scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()).fireOnGlobalLayoutListeners();
```

However the code inside the listener is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

I solve the issue by manually calling the *createView* method of the Fragment with the following parameters:

```
    FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout( RuntimeEnvironment.application );
            fragment.createView( LayoutInflater.from( RuntimeEnvironment.application ), container );
FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout( RuntimeEnvironment.application );
fragment.createView( LayoutInflater.from( RuntimeEnvironment.application ), container );
```

The globalLayoutListener was finally  added and when I executed the following code the *onGlobalLayout()* method was execute properly:

```
shadowOf( fragment.scrollView.getViewTreeObserver() ).fireOnGlobalLayoutListeners();
```